# album art with cursor and base adapter not showing in list or toast

Tags: android, listview, cursor, baseadapter, albumart

album art with cursor and base adapter not showing in list or toast

i am trying to display the album art and album details in a listview however neither does it display in toast or in listview

here is the code

mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //retrieveAudioFiles();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void retrieveAudioFiles(){
        SongsList songsList = new SongsList();

        //Uri sd = Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI ;
        //Uri sd = Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Uri sd = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] cols = {Audio.Media.TITLE,Audio.Media.ARTIST,Audio.Media.ALBUM};
        String where = Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC;
        Cursor audioCursor = getContentResolver().query(sd,cols,where,null,null);

        while (audioCursor.moveToNext()){
            int posColTitle = audioCursor.getColumnIndex(Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int posColArtist = audioCursor.getColumnIndex(Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            int posColAlbum = audioCursor.getColumnIndex(Audio.Media.ALBUM);

            String songTitle = audioCursor.getString(posColTitle);
            String songArtist = audioCursor.getString(posColArtist);
            String songAlbum = audioCursor.getString(posColAlbum);
            int posColId = audioCursor.getColumnIndex(Audio.Media._ID);
            long songId = audioCursor.getLong(posColId);
            Uri songUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,songId);
            String[] dataColumn = {Audio.Media.DATA};
            Cursor coverCursor = getContentResolver().query(songUri, dataColumn, null, null, null);
            coverCursor.moveToFirst();
            int dataIndex = coverCursor.getColumnIndex(Audio.Media.DATA);
            String filePath = coverCursor.getString(dataIndex);
            coverCursor.close();
            MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            retriever.setDataSource(filePath);
            byte[] coverBytes = retriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
            Bitmap songCover;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),audioCursor.getString(audioCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM)), 
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if (coverBytes!=null) //se l'array di byte non è vuoto, crea una bitmap
                songCover = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(coverBytes, 0, coverBytes.length);
            else
                songCover=null;
            songsList.add(new Song(songTitle,songArtist,songAlbum));
            }
        audioCursor.close();
    }
    public class SongsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private SongsList songsList;
        private LayoutInflater songInf;

        public SongsAdapter(Context c, SongsList theSongs){
            super();  
            songsList=theSongs;
            songInf=LayoutInflater.from(c);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return songsList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return songsList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            RowWrapper wrapper;
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = songInf.inflate(
                    R.layout.song_row, null);
                wrapper = new RowWrapper(convertView);
                convertView.setTag(wrapper);
            }
            else
            {
                wrapper = (RowWrapper) convertView.getTag();
            }
            Song song = (Song) getItem(position);
            wrapper.populate(song);

            return convertView;
        }

        private class RowWrapper
        {
            private TextView titleTextView;
            private TextView artistTextView;
            private TextView albumTextView;
            private ImageView coverImageView;

            public RowWrapper(View convertView)
            {
                titleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
                artistTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textArtist);
                albumTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textAlbum);
                coverImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.smallCover);
            }

            public void populate(Song song)
            {
                titleTextView.setText(song.title);
                artistTextView.setText(song.artist);
                albumTextView.setText(song.album);
               if (song.cover != null)
                coverImageView.setImageBitmap(song.cover);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

then in the song class

```
public class Song {

    public String title="";
    public String artist="";
    public String album="";
    public Bitmap cover=null;

    public Song(String t, String ar, String al){
        title=t;
        artist=ar;
        album=al;
        //cover=c;
    }

    public Song(){

    }

}
```

and songList class

```
public class SongsList extends ArrayList<Song> {

    public SongsList(){
        super();
    }

}
```

how ever nothing is displayed

here are the xml files

activty_main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.stackalbumart.MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and song_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:onClick="songPicked" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/smallCover"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:contentDescription="coverDescription"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="labelTitle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="textTitle" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelArtist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:text="labelArtist" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textArtist"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="textArtist" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelAlbum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="labelAlbum" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textAlbum"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="textAlbum" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

the app just opens and there is a blank white screen there is even no error

what really should be done

Comment: you have `audioCursor` so why dont you use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` ?

Comment: i am currently trying to learn android and this is a task i have to do, use cursor and base adapter with album art how can it be done in above code

Comment: if you want to learn android  then use `SimpleCursorAdapter` and not write hundreds lines of redundant code...

Comment: is there an example i can refer to where SimpleCursorAdapter  is used to display album art from mp3 files to be displayed in listview.

Comment: there are tons of examples on how to use `SimpleCursorAdapter`, just ask uncle google

Answer (score 0):

Since you are handle cursor, I would strongly suggest you to subclass `CursorAdapter`, which extends `BaseAdapter` and has the additional logic to handle the Cursor.

About your issue

in your `retrieveAudioFiles()`, after you close your cursor, you should instantiate the adapter and feed it to your ListView. E.g.

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
listView.setAdapter(new SongsAdapter(this, songList));
```

Comment: did as you have said still nothing is displayed

Comment: Check the content of `songList` after the while loop

Comment: actually he doesn't need `songsList` at all

Comment: @abcd use `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor()` to verify the cursor is right

Comment: I agree with you @pskink. But really, SongsAdapter should be  a `static` class

Comment: @Blackbelt i agree, but actually i would use `SimpleCursorAdapter`, simple and easy...

Comment: thank you for the help guys , i am currently in learning phase will get back if i solve my problem , currently it is still unsolved